# Where should I ask advice about what OSI license to use for a new project?

Tags: discussion

The question would be something along the lines of this:

> What OSI license is suitable for an open source library that is only
>   used in unit testing scenarios?

Or more specific:

> Is the MIT license suitable for an open source library that is only
>   used in unit testing scenarios?

From what I understand, it will probably be closed on Stack Overflow. Is Meta Stack Overflow the right place for this question, even though most users are probably not lawyers?

Comment: Programmers.SE has a few similar questions.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is only for questions about the site itself. So it won't be on topic here.

Comment: But you should certainly specify what your requirements are. In particular which kind of virality you want. That can vary from very strong(AGPL) to not at all(permissive such at MIT).

Comment: [I posted the question on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/130771/is-the-mit-license-suitable-for-an-open-source-library-that-is-only-used-in-unit) and added my requirements, the use case and the specific licenses I considered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is a bit of a weak question: asking strangers on the internet how you should license your software is opening yourself up for a bag of hurt.

Asking about a specific license and its suitability  is better: at least you've narrowed it down some. However, you're still basically asking strangers to decide how you ought to license your software, and still opening yourself up for a bag of hurt.

If you wanted to ask about specific questions or concerns you have with an OSI license, like, for example, "How would X clause in the MIT license affect Y situation I'm concerned about?", your best bet is [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), where licensing questions are on-topic.

Of course, you always want to be careful, no matter the licensing question you ask, to not mistake answers as legal advice: we're programmers, not IP lawyers.

Comment: Right, adding specifics to the question would make it less ambiguous. Thanks!

Comment: Ew, Programmers accepts those?  Ew.

Comment: @MatthewRead Expect a flood of crappy Android questions, that we would normally close... :P

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Lol. You wouldn't want me to retaliate by mis-migrating all the SO questions we get, would you? :P

Answer (score 0):

> Is Meta Stack Overflow the right place for this question, even though most users are probably not lawyers?

Meta Stack Overflow is for questions about Stack Exchange. If the question is about a third-party library not used on Stack Exchange, or a feature request to use a third-party library on Stack Exchange sites, then the question is not on-topic here.

[Programmers accept questions about software licensing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), but I cannot assure you your question is accepted there.